# How to deploy delphi exe output to artifactory using jenkins

Tags: delphi, jenkins, deployment, artifactory

I use a script in Jenkins to build delphi projects and I want to deploy their .exe outputs to Artifactory server but I dont know how. Is there any plugin to deploy exe files to Artifactory? 
Is it a good idea to deploy them to Artifactory?

Comment: Is this really a Delphi question? Surely the method to deploy a file is independent of the program used to generate that file. How do you deploy *other* files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best would be using the [Jenkins Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin).
The plugin allows your build jobs to deploy artifacts automatically to Artifactory and have them linked to the build job that created them.
The support for [generic (freestyle) builds](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds) is probably the most suitable one for deploying the .exe files. As part of the support for generic builds, you will be able to defined patterns for selecting which files would be deployed and to where.